# VueJS trying to access data from html using 2 differents variable

Tags: vue.js

so here is the problem, I have 2 array, first one look like this, let's call it A :

```
[{id: 2, otherValue: "hello"}]
```

and the second array look like this, let's call it B :

```
[{1: {title: "title1", text: "message1"}, 2: {title: "title2", text: "message2"}}]
```

What i'm trying to do seems simple but I can't find the right way to do it, I need to render the message of the item in my array B corresponding of the id provided by my array A. In my mind it would look like this but of course it doesn't work :

```
<div id="message">
    {{B[A.id].text}}
</div>
```

Does anyone have the right synthax ? thanks.

Comment: Why is `B` an array? Is it meant to only have one element?

Comment: No, the array B is meant to have potentially infinite number of elements, all containing the value title and text

Comment: Then which element of `B` should correspond to the element in `A`? Are the lengths of both arrays identical with matching elements?

Comment: You need to access the particular element of `B` first at some particular index `i` as `B[i]`, then you can access the property of that object at the given ID as `B[i][id]`. You need to figure out what `i` is, and it isn't clear from your question what it should be.

Comment: the index i i'm trying to access is A.id

Comment: There’s two things here, `B` is an *array* of *objects*, so you will need to index twice to get to the text property. What I’m asking is: which object of `B` corresponds to a particular object of `A`? Do you see that since `B` is an array then it can have many objects where each object has its own mapping from ID to another sub-object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably have to create a method which takes in Array A and B, and then does the `B[A.id]` mapping and returns your desired text.

Edit: Maybe this is not a must, but it is definitely cleaner than doing everything in a html template.

Comment: so i need to call the method like so ?
```
<div id="message">
    {{someMethod(A, B)}}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is my suggestion :).